# Orientdb performance of count with traverse use

Tags: orientdb

I have a database with around 300,000 users and 800,000 relationships between those users, this data can be described like:

User - Contact -> User

I want to know the number of possible new contacts that a specific user can have, so I wrote this query in order to know this number:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (TRAVERSE OUT() FROM (SELECT FROM Usuario WHERE user_id=12345) WHILE $depth <=2) WHERE $depth = 2`

The query take 5 sec (more or less).  I have the same data into a neo4j database and the count for the same level takes 450 ms. So I want to know if exists some way to obtain this information (number of possible new contacts) with best performance.

Comment: Hi Juan, could you share a test db to try your case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good improvement you get by putting a NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX the field user_id.

**EDIT 1**

Another tip that you can try using 'maxdepth' instead of 'while depth <= 2.

SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (TRAVERSE OUT () FROM (SELECT FROM Usuario WHERE user_id = 12345) WHILE $ MAXDEPTH = 2) WHERE $ depth = 2

There is a slight difference in terms of calculation time, due to the fact that the while $depth will be evaluated also at level 3, then the records are skipped because they don't match the while, but in the meantime they were loaded, and it costs execution time. Withmaxdepth you just stop the execution at level 2.

Comment: Hi Isavio, I have it ( I forgot to mention that)

Comment: Thank you Isavio, with this change the execution time was reduced as I expected